# "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)" AWS .pem provided

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, aws

I'm quite new to this and it's the second server that I setup on my own, it should be straight forward and simple but I'm getting this error.

Looked all around but the solutions don't meet my situation.

I'm getting this error even though I'm providing the `.pem` file I just downloaded when creating the instance in AWS.

```
ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/transa.pem ubuntu@0.0.0.0
```

The debugging output is as follows:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "0.0.0.0" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 0.0.0.0 [0.0.0.0] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 0.0.0.0:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/zerinol/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/zerinol/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 0.0.0.0
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:gntDTHD4yKufreZfPzhLh5f46z0XE6/jiOIFJe8d8zo
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/zerinol/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/zerinol/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 0.0.0.0
debug1: Host '0.0.0.0' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/zerinol/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/chaves.pem (0x7fffc9735f10), agent
debug2: key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/transa.pem (0x7fffc97332d0), agent
debug2: key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/chaves.pem
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/transa.pem
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/zerinol/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

I have another `.pem` file that I use in another account with no problem, both are being loaded to the `ssh-agent` using `.bashrc`, I don't know if it has anything to do with this. Why does one work fine while the other one doesn't and how can I make it work?

I'm on Windows 10 using Linux shell (`wsl`)

Comment: Have you double triple-checked that the EC2 box is expecting that key pair? PS: there's little point zeroing out the IP address in your example if you leave it in the debug logs :-)

Comment: well, yes its quite the same kind I use with another account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ec2 key-pair file has to have restricted permission and you need to do that with admin privilege. Without admin privilege, it may not show any error. So, you may think that the permission has been changed.

```
sudo su
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/transa.pem
```

Comment: That works ok for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, It was because I had to add the user name.

Trying to ssh without using the username.

```
$ ssh -vvv -i  ~/.ssh/aws.pem 52.88.251.23

Error message: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Worked with this(The default user name `ec2-user` 
):

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/aws.pem ec2-user@52.88.251.23
```